# Creating panel data from cross-sectional and time series data

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I have two pieces of data.
First, cross-sectional data-1600 corn field data
Second, weather data for the corresponding counties for the corn field area from 2013 to 2020. -Date is year, month, day
I want to create panel data using two kinds of data.

The problem is to join the weather data in each field for each year, month, and day (like vlookup in Excel).

For example, the two tables below.

1. Cross-section

| ID | county | Longtitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Texas | -101.8259 | 36.99026 |
| 2 | Cimarron | -101.7264 | 36.99253 |
| 3 | Texas | -101.8038 | 36.99012 |
| 4 | Cimarron | -101.9427 | 36.97605 |
| 5 | Cimarron | -102.2219 | 36.96172 |
| 6 | Beaver | -102.0777 | 36.96919 |
| 7 | Beaver | -101.6181 | 36.98999 |

2. Time series data

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | county | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013 | 1 | 1 | Texas | 1 | 5 |
| 2013 | 1 | 2 | Texas | 2 | 6 |
| 2013 | 1 | 3 | Texas | 3 | 7 |
| 2013 | 1 | 4 | Texas | 4 | 8 |
| 2014 | 1 | 1 | Texas | 9 | 10 |
| 2014 | 1 | 2 | Texas | 11 | 12 |
| 2014 | 1 | 3 | Texas | 13 | 14 |
| 2014 | 1 | 4 | Texas | 15 | 16 |

The data I want to create is below.

| ID | county | Longtitude | Latitude | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | county | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Texas | -101.8259 | 36.99026 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | Texas | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | Cimarron | -101.7264 | 36.99253 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | Cimarron | - | - |
| 3 | Texas | -101.8038 | 36.99012 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | Texas | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | Cimarron | -101.9427 | 36.97605 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | Cimarron | - | - |
| 5 | Cimarron | -102.2219 | 36.96172 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | Cimarron | - | - |
| 6 | Beaver | -102.0777 | 36.96919 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | Beaver | - | - |
| 7 | Beaver | -101.6181 | 36.98999 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | Beaver | - | - |
| 1 | Texas | -101.8259 | 36.99026 | 2013 | 1 | 2 | Texas | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | Cimarron | -101.7264 | 36.99253 | 2013 | 2 | 1 | Cimarron | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | Texas | -101.8038 | 36.99012 | 2013 | 1 | 2 | Texas | 2 | 6 |
| 4 | Cimarron | -101.9427 | 36.97605 | 2013 | 1 | 2 | Cimarron | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | Cimarron | -102.2219 | 36.96172 | 2013 | 1 | 2 | Cimarron | - |  |
| 6 | Beaver | -102.0777 | 36.96919 | 2013 | 1 | 2 | Beaver | 1 | 5 |
| 7 | Beaver | -101.6181 | 36.98999 | 2013 | 1 | 2 | Beaver | 1 | 5 |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Texas | -101.8259 | 36.99026 | 2014 | 1 | 4 | Texas | 15 | 16 |
| 2 | Cimarron | -101.7264 | 36.99253 | 2014 | 2 | 4 | Cimarron | 15 | 16 |
| 3 | Texas | -101.8038 | 36.99012 | 2014 | 1 | 2 | Texas | 15 | 16 |
| 4 | Cimarron | -101.9427 | 36.97605 | 2014 | 1 | 4 | Cimarron | - | - |
| 5 | Cimarron | -102.2219 | 36.96172 | 2014 | 1 | 4 | Cimarron | - | - |
| 6 | Beaver | -102.0777 | 36.96919 | 2014 | 1 | 4 | Beaver | - | - |
| 7 | Beaver | -101.6181 | 36.98999 | 2014 | 1 | 4 | Beaver | - | - |

-Is a number other than NA.

In other words, I want to perform 1 cross section for each date using a function like left_join and rbind the data to create panel data.

If I want to make a panel from January 1, 2013 to January 1, 2014,
I need to use 7 observations * 3 (counts) *365 (dates).
My data is much more than this, so I use a loop (1600 observations, 77 counties, 10 years).

If you give me any ideas, I appreciate it!

edit:
In other words, considering only the two of January 1st and January 2nd, left_join variables such as tavg of 1600 fields of table 1 (using data from the 1st), repeat the same process on the 2nd, and then combine the two data. Is. That is, 1600*2 data are generated (of course, the values of the tavg variables on the 1st and 2nd days are different). I have to take this course for 10 years.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand yet what you have tried and how the result varied from your goal. Why wouldn't `dplyr::left_join(table1, table2)` suffice?

Comment: Your code works fine in the simple case above. I want to left_join each field by date and list those data by date.
This is because the values of A and B are different for each date. The code I'm trying to do is this. for (i in 2013:2014) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
    for (k in 1:2) {
      C <-rbind(left_join(field, filter(J, YEAR==i & MONTH==j &DAY==k), by = c("county" = "county")))
    }
  }
}

Comment: Can you give an example of where a left_join doesn't give you what you want? It would append the respective A and B value columns where the other keys (ID, county, date) match. Are you looking for output in a different shape than what you described in the question, where instead of A and B you have 'col_name" and "value" and those two values go into separate rows? That could be done with `left_join(table1, table2 %>% pivot_longer(-c(YEAR:county)))`

Comment: If the above output is shown as a picture, it is like the picture in the body. In other words, considering only the two of January 1st and January 2nd, left_join variables such as tavg of 1600 fields of table 1 (using data from the 1st), repeat the same process on the 2nd, and then combine the two data. Is. That is, 1600*2 data are generated (of course, the values of the tavg variables on the 1st and 2nd days are different). I have to take this course for 10 years.